# Error: export 'CSP_NONCE' (imported as 'CSP_NONCE') was not found in '@angular/core'

Tags: angular

I have this error after installed @anglur/cdk with npm. Someone know the soluttion to this issue?

I tried to delete node_module and package-lock.json and re-install, but the problem remains. I didn't find anything can help me.

Comment: can you share the output of `ng version` ?

Comment: Angular CLI: 15.2.1

Comment: We need the whole output.

Comment: Angular CLI: 15.2.1
Node: 18.12.0
Package Manager: npm 8.19.2
OS: win32 x64
This one?

Comment: It should also include the packages versions.

Answer (score 0):

The `CSP_NONCE` `InjectionToken` was added in Angular v16.

You likely have a version mismatch in your app : a v16 CDK but a v15 core.

Comment: Thank you. I downgrade CDK to version 15.2.9 and now it works